# Regex with comments

Tags: python, regex

The below is to parse a lisp expression (doing as much as possible in 'one go'). How does it look, and what can be improved?

```
# goal: capture the next token then get the rest of the line
#       to be used in a while-loop/yield
tokenizer = re.compile(r"""

   \s*          # any amount of whitespace...
   
   # 1. capture group one: token
   (
     ,@                     # special token ,@ ...
    |[(),`']                # or ) ( , ' ` ...
    |"(?:[^\\"]*(?:\\.)*)*" # or match on string (unrolling the loop)...
    |;.*                    # or comment-anything...
    |[^\s('"`,;)]*          # or non-special...
   )

   # 2. capture group two: rest-of-line
   (.*)                     
""", re.VERBOSE)
```

Example run (python):

```
line = '(define (square x) (* x x))'
while line:
    token, line = tokenizer.match(line).groups()
    print (token)
```

Comment: Typically, a lexer will complain if given invalid inputs. Yours will tokenize anything. Perhaps it would help for you to clarify the goal(s) of this code.

Comment: Your *(unrolling the loop)* part is wrong and should be: `"[^\\"]*(?:\\.[^\\"]*)*"`

Answer (score -2):

It's difficult for me to say whether this is well-written or not since there are no tests, and that's fundamentally your biggest problem. A complex regex like this couldn't represent a better subject for unit testing. It's already well-isolated, it's important, somewhat internally complex, and would benefit from spelling out exactly which inputs and outputs you expect. Include in your tests as many edge cases as you can think of, and also the "good" (inputs that you expect to successfully parse) as well as the "bad" (inputs that you expect should fail to parse in expected ways).

The regex itself doesn't seem crazy. I find the lack of `^` and `$` suspicious. If you accidentally send this through a `search` instead of a `match`, you leave yourself open to false positives.